# Get current EAR path with WebLogic

Tags: java, weblogic, ear

In my source code, I'd like to get programmatically, the last modified date of the current EAR from which my code is deployed.
I'm using Oracle WebLogic.
How could I do that?

Thx for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest stepping back and looking at the problem you're trying to solve, Eric.

Do you want to know when the application was built or the particular version of the application you've got deployed? If that's the case, you're probably best served by incorporating something into the build process to set this. Ideally a manifest of the specific component versions used to package up your application.

If you want to know when the application was first deployed by an administrator, or most recently deployed that gets more tricky. Relying on the filesystem to solve this problem is a bad idea because you're at the mercy of whatever WebLogic Server is doing, which is admittedly more than a bit opaque.

If you absolutely need to do this, WebLogic Server's standard staging behaviour puts a version of the file in a particular subdirectory on each server instance, then very quickly pulls it apart. (it's the 'servers//stage' subdirectory underneath the root directory of the domain ($DOMAIN_HOME) $DOMAIN_HOME is the current directory for all server processes at runtime, so the relative path should work fine.

That *should* give you the time that file was deployed across the network, but you'd definitely want to test the observed behaviour from rebooting your server instance.

The problem with that is that it doesn't give you anything you couldn't determine more elegantly via either the build process, or WLST scripting around the deployment process.

If it's the last time the application itself was deployed (regardless of the version) then application lifecycle event listeners are definitely the best way to go. Unfortunately there's no MBean that gives you the uptime of an individual application.

There's a great reference on lifecycle listeners here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13712/app_events.htm#i178290

Answer (score 0):

You could either check the file properties or see inside the MANIFEST.MF present inside the EAR.

Comment: Thx, but the main challenge is to retrieve this EAR path... How could I do that?